# pass a member function as argument in libclang visitor

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, libclang

I am using LibClang to traverse AST in a C++ program as below:

```
CXChildVisitResult visitor(CXCursor cursor, CXCursor parent, CXClientData data) {
  // some code
}

int main() {
  // some code
  clang_visitChildren(rootCursor, visitor, 0);
}
```

I do not know how to pass `visitor` to `clang_visitChildren()` if `visitor()` is a member of a class. I tried using `ClassName::visitor` instead of visitor, but I get the following compiler error:

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘CXChildVisitResult ClassName::visitor(CXCursor, CXCursor, CXClientData)’
```

Comment: `0` never means nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clang_visitChildren` only accepts regular functions, not member functions. It order to use a member function with it you will have to create a helper static member function that will call a non-static one:

```
class MyVisitor
{
public:
  CXChildVisitResult visitor(CXCursor, CXCursor);
  static CXChildVisitResult visitorHelper(CXCursor cursor, CXCursor parent, CXClientData client_data) {
    return static_cast<MyVisitor *>(client_data)->visitor(cursor, parent);
  }
};

int main() {
  MyVisitor myVisitor;
  // some code
  clang_visitChildren(rootCursor, &MyVisitor::visitorHelper, &myVisitor);
}
```

Note the use of `client_data` parameter to pass a pointer to an object whose method you want to call. This is a very common pattern for callback in C API.

Alternatively you may want to choose a different library to work with Clang (more info [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html)) such as [LibTooling](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html) which provides a C++ interface.

Comment: Note that you don't _have_ to use a static member function, it could just as well be a free function. The effect (and idea) is of course the same.

Comment: @MaxLanghof, yes, but I think static function is more appropriate since it's closely related to the class (see [cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science))) and also preserves encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

Passing member functions as arguments is easy. The trick is the syntax. You don't need static functions you need a pointer to the member function and a pointer to the calling object.

See this example

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
    public:
    virtual void MemberFunc() {
        std::cout << "MemberFunc called" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void MemberFuncWithArgs(int a, std::string b, double c) {
        std::cout << "MemberFuncWithArgs called with a = " << a << " b = " << b << " c = " << c << std::endl;
    }
};

class Bar : public Foo {
    public:
    virtual void MemberFunc() {
        std::cout << "Bar MemberFunc called" << std::endl;
    }
};

// funPtr is a pointer to the function in the class Foo:: scope that takes zero arguments and returns void
void CallClassFunction(void (Foo::*funPtr)(), Foo* obj) {
    // We deference the function pointer and invoke it on the caller
    (obj->*funPtr)();  
}

// Same as above but funPtr takes 3 arguments
void CallClassFunctionWithArgs(void (Foo::*funPtr)(int a, std::string b, double c), int a, std::string b, double c, Foo* obj) {
    (obj->*funPtr)(a, b, c);
}

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";

    Foo obj;

    // We take the address of the class member function (makes a pointer)
    // We take a pointer to the obj variable
    CallClassFunction(&Foo::MemberFunc, &obj);
    CallClassFunctionWithArgs(&Foo::MemberFuncWithArgs, 34, "hello", 65.87, &obj);


    // Works with inheritance too! This will now call Bar::MemberFunc
    Bar bar;

    CallClassFunction(&Foo::MemberFunc, &bar);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This in no way helps to use a member function with **an existing C API** which is the case here.

Comment: OP says they are using C++

Comment: @r3musn0x Hm, maybe the question could make it more clear that this is a C API then? It's not obvious at all (unless you're familiar with LibClang).

Comment: OP is using C++ with a library that provides a C API.

Comment: @MaxLanghof, the question is explicitly tagged `libclang` which implies that the answer should account for that.

Comment: OP wanted to pass a member function into a visitor class in C++. I show how OP can do that without explicitly doing all the work for him.

Comment: The question literally states `how to pass visitor to clang_visitChildren` where `visitor` is a member function and `clang_visitChildren` is a C library function that accepts a pointer to a regular function.

Comment: visitor is a design pattern as well and OP states C++.

Comment: besides you can easily bind the member function example in a non-member callback via a utility function and it would work.